# Little $o$ notation and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I have this question:

> Consider the series
>
> $e^{\tan(x)} = 1 + x + \dfrac{x^{2}}{2!} + \dfrac{3x^{3}}{3!} + \dfrac{9x^{4}}{4!} + \ldots $
>
> Retaining three terms in the series, estimate the remaining series using
> "*Little*-$o$" notation with the best integer value possible, as $x\to 0$.

My question is:

What do they mean with "with the best integer value possible"? Someone who can point out the connection with little $o$ notation and a best integer vaulue possible?

Comment: It would greatly help matters if you included the precise question and its source.

Comment: Probably they're envisioning something like $... + o(x^5)$ where $5$ could be something else but is supposed to be the best integer that make the estimate work.

Comment: Three terms in the series make $1+x+\frac12x^2$ hence the question asks for the smallest possible $n$ such that $\exp(\tan(x))=1+x+\frac12x^2+o(x^n)$ when $x\to0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Best’ here would be ‘smallest’, so as Henning said, in all likelihood you’re being asked to write $e^{\tan x} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^n)$ as $x\to 0$ for the smallest integer $n$ that makes the statement true.

**Added:** As Brugerfugl points out, that should be ‘largest’, since were’ looking at $x\to 0$.

Comment: Well. I have now realized that it must be the biggest integer n, because the situation is x->0 and not x-> infinity

When x->0 we have: 

x^-1 = o(x^-2)

and when x->infinity

x^-2 = o(x^-1)

Comment: @Brugerfugl: You’re quite right: I wasn’t thinking when I wrote that. My apologies; I’ll edit it.